# Registering a new user in the Model layer. Am I doing it right?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have been reading up on DDD a lot over the last few days and could not find one solid example of how someone would go about simply registering a user on their site so after lots of reading I have stuck this together and I would like your feedback on it because I am sure it is far from perfect, it might even be completely wrong but here it goes:

**RegisterController**

```
$userMapper = $this->dataMapperFactory->build('user');
if($userMapper->fetchByUsername($username) !== NULL) {
    // Error: The chosen username already exists
}
else {

    if($userMapper->fetchByEmail($email) !== NULL) {
        // Error: The email address already exists
    }
    else {

        $userDO = $this->domainObjectFactory->build('user');
        // Set the properties of the $userDO object here with the ones
        // from the registration form

        // Insert the new user into the database            
        $userMapper->save($userDO);

    }

}
```

I have done all the form validation with my own `FormValidation` class so when I add the properties to the $userDO object they are all 100% ready to be inserted into the database (correct length, type, format, ranges etc) so how does the code look to you?

I think I am on the right track and I would really appreciate any tips on how to improve my code.

Also, the way I am checking if the username they chose has already been taken, is there a better way to do that? Instead of having to create an object each time to check? Like the old way I used to do it with a simple:

```
SELECt COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = 'john'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a code review site. However codereview.stackexchange.com is.

Comment: This looks okay to me. I'd probably not fetch the Users through the DataMapper but a Repository though. Also, I'd add a RegisterUserService that does the actual insertion to keep the controller thin. The controller should only check that the required values to delegate to the Service are there and then try/catch the delegation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you say a register register user service do you mean a whole new class or just a UserService class with a register() method? And also, the last part about the simple SQL query to find find out something small like if a username already exists, can you not do that any more if you are using domain objects and datamappers?

Comment: @Gordon , you only need the try-catch if view instance is not requesting data from the model layer. It kinda depends on what role you assign to the controllers.

Comment: @David RegisterUserService. Basically, I'd have a class for every UseCase in your application. The Controllers only trigger these. Re SQL query: you can have simple things. In fact, simple is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Some theory-related "blah":

As you might be aware, the core concept of MVC and MVC-inspired design patterns is the [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). It dictates that you divide these patterns in to major layers: presentation layer and domain model layer.

In this case it is significant, because you current structure of controller contains *application logic* (the interaction domain logic entities and storage abstractions), whereas a controller should be only responsible for altering state of model layer (and sometimes - the current view) based on user input.

You end up violating bot the above mentioned SoC and also [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

> <sub>**Note:** in context of web based MVC variations the *"user"* is a web browser, not the person sitting behind it.</sub>

Instead you should encapsulate the application logic in services (as [@Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166197/registering-a-new-user-in-the-model-layer-am-i-doing-it-right#comment19627174_14166197) mentioned). In a fully realized model layer the different services become something like a *public-ish* API through which the presentation layer interacts with model.

Though, unlink Gordon, I would recommend your service to be a bit broader. In case of user registration, I would make it a part of `CommunityService` or maybe `MembershipService`. A structure that handles all the aspects of the user account management as far as the model layer is concerned.

#### The code bits:

One way for using in controller would look something like:

```
public function postUser( $request )
{
    $community = $this->serviceFactory->build('Community');
    $community->addUser( $request->getParameter('username'),
                         $request->getParameter('password'),
                         $request->getParameter('repeated_password'),
                         $request->getParameter('email') );
}
```

While this is a valid way, you might already notice an possible problem. Even when user registration need only the minimum of data, the amount of parameters that you end up passing to the service makes it hard to use.

Passing the `$request` on to service is **not a valid improvement**. You would just end up violating [Law of Demeter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter). Instead i would recommend something like:

```
$keys = ['username', 'password', 'repeated_password', 'email'];
$community->addUser( $request->getParameters( $keys ) );
```

Where the `getParameters()` method is implemented similar to:

```
public function getParameters( $keys )
{
    $response = [];
    foreach( $keys as $parameter )
    {
        $response[ $parameter ] = $this->getParameter( $parameter );
    }
    return $response;
}
```

#### Domain logic and validation

You mentioned, that some `FormValidation` class, that you are using to make sure, that your instance of `User` [domain object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) receives proper values. Actually the data validation is one of the domain object's responsibilities. You still might use a separate validation class, to avoid code duplication, but that would be a dependency, which is injected by domain object's factory to share between instances.

> <sub>**Note:** in my personal experience, the duplication for validation is quite rare for anything but the null-checks. Each of complicated validation rule-sets are targeted at fields of one specific domain object. That, in my opinion, makes a validation class quite redundant ... unless you expect to share same validation class between multiple projects.</sub>

The code-flow usually is such that, when you need to store the data from domain object, you check if it has not acquired an error state, and if there is an error, you actually dump it in session, for a retrieval after redirect.

```
if ( $user->isValid() )
{
    $sqlMapper->store( $user );
}
else
{
    $sessionMapper->storeUser();
}
```

In this use-case pre-validated input ends up actually being harmful.

Comment: Great answer. Special emphasis should be placed on the note about data validation; All that should happen generically at forms is basic validation like !empty or NaN, with the specifics like length limits or special characters defined in the domain objects. It might seem tedious at first, but having that validation in the domain layer gives you complete confidence that values going into and coming out of the database are formatted exactly as intended for the given domain object.